# Connector installation error (MySQL installer)

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I'm installing MySQL 5.6 Community Edition using MySQL installer and everything was installed properly except for "Connector/Python 2.7 1.1.6".

Upon mousing over, I get the error message "The product requires Python 2.7 but it was not detected on this machine. Python 2.7 requires manual installation and must be installed prior to installing this product"

The problem is, I have Python 2.7 installed in C: already and I can't seem to direct this detection towards where I have Python 2.7.

(I am using Windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any install path dependencies on your installer to figure out if your python is in the right place.

But I recommend that you install the connector you want manually.

P.S. Are you sure you need the connector? Or you just saw the error and assumed you need it?